# How to invoke partial view from action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to invoke partial view from action method with passing model data and when  partial view will be process and UI generated then i want to store the partial view html in variable with in action .

i know that people often load partial view from JavaScript like the below way and store partial view result into js variable.

so just guide me if possible to invoke partial view from action method and how to store partial view result into variable with in action method. thanks

```
public PartialViewResult yourpartialviewresult()
{
    return PartialView("partialview", model);
}


client side
-----------
var html;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/home/yourpartialviewresult',
    dataType: 'html', //be sure to use html dataType
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data){
        html = data;
    },
    complete: function(){ }
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can create a method as, which will accept `ViewName` and `Model` it will return HTML string

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
{
    controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View,
                controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage also you have to return `JsonResult` instead of `PartialViewResult`

```
public JsonResult yourpartialviewresult()
{
    return Json(new
            {
                data = RenderRazorViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "partialview", model)
            });
}
```

Comment: can't we call/invoke partial view directly from controller ? there is no way ?

Comment: @Thomas, As per my understanding and knowledge No we don't have a way.

Answer (score 4):

You can render `Partial Views` directly into the `View` Using `Html.Partial` or `Html.Action`. Both return a `MvcHtmlString`, so makes this simple:

Using Html.Partial

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = '@Html.Raw(Html.Partial("_Partial", Model).ToString().Replace("\r\n", ""))';
</script>
```

Using Html.Acition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = '@Html.Raw(Html.Action("actionName", "controllerName").ToString().Replace("\r\n", ""))';
</script>
```

This code calls the strongly `Partial View`, passing the `Model`. Converting It into a string is necessary to replace all scape `'\r\n'` characteres.

Then, using `HTML.Raw` return a Raw HTML string.

This code must stay into the **View** that you are creating the variable.

Works like a charm here!